# Remove top margin from any element, first in div

Tags: css, selector, margin, padding

Can you remove the top margin and padding from the first element in a div? So if the first element is a paragraph or a header there's no top margin.

The first element could be anything. The idea is not having to write all the permutations of elements, but I will do if I need to.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You want to use the :first-child selector

```
.parent :first-child { margin-top:0; }
```

Comment: Ace thank you. I didn't realise you could do that with a space between class and pseudo

Answer (score 1):

If your parent div has a class of `.parent`, you can find the first child element with the CSS [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child) selector.

So you can use:

```
.parent:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```